# How can I avoid "Zip end of central directory signature not found (Zip::Error)" with rubyzip?

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I'm reading a lot of zip file with rubyzip.

However this error message is always showing in only specific file even it is zip file.

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubyzip-1.2.1/lib/zip/central_directory.rb:143:in `get_e_o_c_d': Zip end of central directory signature not found (Zip::Error)

I guess this error occures in rubyzip.

How can I manage this error?

Here is my code.

```
url = 'http://example.zip'

zipfilename = open(url)

Zip::File.open(zipfilename, :allow_redirections => :all) do |zip_file|

   entry = zip_file.glob("*ixbrl.htm").first

   stream = entry.get_input_stream.read

   puts stream

end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to open that zip file with other programs? Did you verify that the zip file itself is not corrupt or that is is a multipart zip and some parts are missing?

Comment: @spickermann Hi, thank you for response! Yes, it works fine in PHP and local Ruby program. That error is happened only in heroku. I'm not familiar about verifying that the zip file if it's corrupt.. May I ask??

Comment: @T.Akashi did you ever solve this?

Comment: for me it was because the zip file didn't exist, or at least you can check the location to the zip source is correct

Answer (score 8):

I faced this error when I try to extract data from a uploaded `.xlsx` file in my application. On my context, the `.xlsx` file was corrupted, so my solution was save the content (I usually handle the buffer file after the upload) as a csv file (in my application I dont need to worry about the file extension), fixing the content by force it to encode as utf-8, and extract it's data after it. [here is](https://gist.github.com/MattPorto/7ecbd1153756a5396dbfc96948cb0e97) a example of the code, I'm using [`roo-xls`](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo-xls) gem to handle `.xls` files and [`roo`](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) gem to handle `.csv` and `.xlsx` files.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error. Also only reproducible on Heroku. The error was fixed after I added an unzip buildpack (second, after Ruby).

https://github.com/davidlibrera/heroku-buildpack-unzip

Comment: I am not using Heroku but running into this issue locally. The root cause of the issue seems to be file names (in the zip) without the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a google docs xlsx file try checking if the access of the sheet link is public.